# Insert a COMMA after p,q,r,s... no. of char in a multiline file

Tags: python, csv, text

I have a huge file of ascii chars (million lines). I want to convert this to a `.csv` file in which the first column would have `m` chars second would have `n` chars and so on `number of columns` and the `number of character in respective col` will be fixed.This should happen to every line of the file. And yes the lines in file will just contain [a-z] [A-Z] and [0-9]. (no special char, includind space)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be posted on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: this is not a code review... code is posted to show my approach you can suggest better ways to do the same thing which can have no relation to the posted code sir

Comment: If this is **working code** that you think could be improved, then yes [codereview.se] is the place for it. If not, please clarify the problem.

Comment: SO isn't a code-writing service. Removing the code isn't helping. It's not clear why you're so resistant to the advice above.

Comment: i think the edit made the post eligible... u  need to chill a bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import csv

numCols = int(raw_input("How many columns does your data have? "))
colWidths = [int(raw_input("How many characters in column %d " %i)) for i in xrange(1, numCols+1)]

infilepath = raw_input("Enter the file name: ")
outfilepath = infilepath.rsplit('.',1)[0]+'.csv'

with open(infilepath) as infile, open(outfilepath, 'w') as fout:
    outfile = csv.writer(fout)
    for line in infile:
        top = 0
        row = []
        for col in colWidths:
            row.append(line[top:top+col])
            top += col
        outfile.writerow(row)
```